# Create multiple instance of a class with different parameters

Tags: java, design-patterns

Below is my initializer  class in which I am creating multiple instance of `Handler` class:

```
@Singleton
public class Initializer {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getInstance(Initializer.class);
  private Handler handlerA;
  private Handler handlerB;
  private Handler handlerC;
  private Handler handlerD;
  // add another handler

  private Initializer() {

  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void postInit() {
    handlerA = new Handler(Type.A, 1);
    handlerB = new Handler(Type.B, 1);
    handlerC = new Handler(Type.C, 1);
    handlerD = new Handler(Type.D, 1);
    // add another handler instance
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    handlerA.shutdown();
    handlerB.shutdown();
    handlerC.shutdown();
    handlerD.shutdown();
    // add another handler shutdown
  }
}
```

And below is my Handler constructor:

```
  public Handler(Type type, int poolSize) {
    this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++) {
      Loop loop = HandlerFactory.getInstance().create(type);
      loops.add(loop);
      executorService.submit(loop);
    }
  }
```

My question is - If I need to add another `handlerE` in my `Initializer` class, then I need to add this line:

```
private Handler handlerE;
```

And then add another line in `postInit()` and `shutdown()` method. It looks ok but I was wondering if there is any better way to write that? If I have to add 10 more handlers, then it will be a single line for all those.

Wanted to see if there is any better way to write those Handlers in my Initializer class. I am working with Java7.

Comment: Have you one and one distinct Handler by Type ? Or a Type may have multiple Handlers ?

Comment: A type can have only one handler not multiple.

Comment: Ok. I will propose you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use of course a `List` to store the `Handler`s in the `Initializer` class.

But as you also search a way where the `Initializer` class would have less impact when `Handler`s are added (and deleted I assume too), I think that you should give more responsibility to the `Type` enum in order that the `Initializer` class delegate to them the `Handler` instantiation task.

As you said that you have one and only distinct `Handler` by Type, you could handle the configuration and the instantiation of the `Handler` in the side of the `Type` enum.
 
Each enum should have a constructor to set the required properties to create a Handler.
In this way, when you add/modify/delete a handler, you don't need to change the `Initializer` class.

Besides, you could also set the `poolSize` directly in the enum declaration and you can could enable or disable a `Handler` for a type as you suggest this need in a comment.

Here is the `Type` enum (I have disabled the `Handler` for the `E` value for the example):

```
public enum Type {

    A(1, true), B(1, true), C(1, true), D(1, true), E(1, false);

    private int poolSize;
    private boolean isHandlerEnabled;

    Type(int poolSize, boolean isHandlerEnabled) {
        this.poolSize = poolSize;
        this.isHandlerEnabled = isHandlerEnabled;
    }

    public int getPoolSize() {
        return poolSize;
    }

    public boolean isHandlerEnabled() {
        return isHandlerEnabled;
    }
    public createHandler(){
       if (!isHandlerEnabled){
           return null;
       }
       return new Handler(this, poolSize);
    }    
}
```

Here is the Initializer class:

```
public class `Initializer` {
    private List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    @PostConstruct
    public void postInit() {
       for (Type type : Type.values()){
          Handler handler = type.createHandler();
          if (handler != null){
             handlers.add(handler);
          }
       }                      
    }
    ...

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        for(Handler handler : handlers) {
            handler.shutdown();
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not store them in a `HashMap`?

```
public class Initializer {
    private final Map<Type, Handler> handlers = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    @PostConstruct
    public void postInit() {
        handlers.put(Type.A, new Handler(Type.A, 1));
        handlers.put(Type.B, new Handler(Type.B, 1));
        handlers.put(Type.C, new Handler(Type.C, 1));
        handlers.put(Type.D, new Handler(Type.D, 1));
        handlers.put(Type.E, new Handler(Type.E, 1));
    }
    ...

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        for(Handler handler : handlers.values()) {
            handler.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am working with Java 7. Can you provide an example basis on that?

Comment: What is the goal of the map here ? A List could do the job.

Comment: @davidxxx I agree; Not knowing enough about how the class is used, and if a particular handler would need to be accessed, I just chose a container I thought would be useful. If there is no reason to lookup a handler then yes, I agree list would be better :^)

Comment: Sometimes we write a little fast our answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Type` is an enum and you want a `Handler` for each type, you can iterate over the `values` in the enum, create a new `Handler` and store the result in a `List`.

Comment: Yes type is an enum. Sometimes we comment out some handler in the initializer class (as we don't need while doing some testing) but generally we use  all the handlers for each type.Can you provide an example how will I do that?

Comment: Well, I've walked through the algorithm for it.  Is there a specific step you're struggling with?  I'm trying not to turn this into a "gimme teh codez" question.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `Type` enum values like this.

```
 @PostConstruct
  public void postInit() {
    for (Type type : Type.values()) {
      handlersList.add(new Handler(type, 1));
    }
  }
```